# Microsoft Excel 2013 how to convert numbers into months in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to convert values from 1 to 12 from a month into text like:
1=January and   2   =February and so on.

The problem is there is one more value 13 in this column which I want to ignore  and leave it blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(A1>12,"",TEXT(DATE(2017,A1,1),"mmmm"))
```

This will read the value in A1 and if 12 or lower it will return the month name that corresponds with the number.

[image]

Comment: @DiveshSharma please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @DiveshSharma, on SU the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just did a little modification to the data and created it as a table with the  name InterimReviewTbl. Then i modified the formula with =IF(InterimReviewTbl[[#All],[Month ]]>12,"",TEXT(DATE(2017,InterimReviewTbl[[#All],[Month ]],1),"mmmm")). The formula works fine but it gives december to the rows in which i have added no data.